# Высота TextButton в DateTimeRangePicker'е не изменяется

Tags: button, flutter, dart

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку сохранения в _CalendarRangePickerDialog высотой 16. Но какие бы я ограничения на неё не ставил, её высота не меняется. Глянул в дерево виджетов, где увидел следующее:

В дереве виджетов с привязкой рендер объекта видно, что мои ограничения на контейнер устанавливаются (1, 4). Но потом ниже видно, что в рендер объекте откуда-то появляется высота 56 (2 и 3), которой в коде нигде нет. Ни в стилях кнопки, но в контейнерах над ней

[image]

Мой код (пытался навесить все, что можно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать как это можно починить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код вставляйте текстом.